# Get image link from div using xPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, uwp, html-agility-pack

Need help to get album cover from webpage.

```
<div class="cover" style="background-image: url("http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/68/b5/08/68b50896-607e-2950-3530-de172fdbf878/source/100x100bb.jpg");"></div>
```

Tried everything but nothing works.

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://www.antena1.com.br/stream/player");
String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
resultat.LoadHtml(source);

HtmlNode nodes1 = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='CuboPlayer1']/div[1]");


txtImgLink.Text = nodes1.ToString();
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where is `CuboPlayer1` in the above `div` element ? Is it parent ?

Comment: div i need is inside  CuboPlayer1 div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to parse out the URL from the InnerHtml of your `CuboPlayer1` div.
Why the parent div and not the cover itself? Because there is a problem with the HtmlAgilityPack where it can't parse out quotes inside `Attributes["style"].Value`, that's why you need to go to the parent node `CuboPlayer1` and manually extract the URL from the entire HTML instead.

You can do that with this code:

```
string nodeHTML = resultat.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='CuboPlayer1']").InnerHtml;

string pattern = @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string backgroundURL = regex.Match(nodeHTML).Value;
```

I tested this using the code below and it works:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = 
        "<div id=\"CuboPlayer1\"><div class=\"cover\" style=\"background-image: url(\"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/68/b5/08/68b50896-607e-2950-3530-de172fdbf878/source/100x100bb.jpg\");\"></div></div>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        string nodeHTML = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
            .SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='CuboPlayer1']").InnerHtml;

        string pattern = @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string backgroundURL = regex.Match(nodeHTML).Value;

        Console.WriteLine(backgroundURL);
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
There is a problem with what you're trying to achieve, in that the background-image is constantly changing. Depending on what is on the screen at the time the document loads, you may not get any URL back because no cover is being displayed.

In any case, here's updated code which points directly at the page you're working with using your URL instead of static HTML like my first example:

```
var url = "http://www.antena1.com.br/stream/player";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(url);

// Convert each line of HTML into a list of strings
List<string> nodeHTML = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='CuboPlayer1']").InnerHtml.Split('\n').ToList();

// Find div with "cover" attribute
string coverHTML = nodeHTML.Where(n => n.Contains("<div class=\"cover\"")).FirstOrDefault();

// Define regular expression to match
string pattern = @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#_]*)?";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Extract backgroundURL
string backgroundURL = regex.Match(coverHTML).Value;
```

Comment: When i am using var html you provided, it works, but using "http://www.antena1.com.br/stream/player" to get data it does not work.  Thanks a lot

Comment: I updated the code, but you may not be able to obtain the cover on inital page load.

Comment: It works but i get http://www.antenna1.fm/ wich is inside: <a target="_blank" class="linkParent" href="http://www.antenna1.fm/"><div class="linkRoma"><p>VISITE A PÁGINA DA ANTENA 1 ROMA <i class="fa fa-plane"></i></p></div></a>

Comment: I am getting empty string, although cover div is not empty. I dont know what I am doing wrong.  Thanks

Comment: It always returns <div class="cover"></div> although div is not empty on webpage.

Comment: Unfortunately as I mentioned, the page HTML is dynamic so when HTML agility pack first loads the page, there is no content for the cover. The cover URL only appears once the player is able to establish a successful connection. You may need to research ways to handle the dynamic nature of the page.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help.